# Multi instance DSP C Source code

Tags: dsp-core

I need to design a  multi instance DSP algorithm implementation. Any reference Open C source code available ?  Any links on multi instance implementations.

-ben

Comment: what might *"a multi instance DSP algorithm implementation"* do? are the instances identical copies of each other or totally different animals? consider what is the difference between resources like read-only data and states.  which are replicated for each instance and which need not be?

Comment: Algorithm or code implementation is same only data keeps changing.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this book super helpful as a c++ audio programmer.  "Designing Audio Effect Plug Ins in C++"  [http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Audio-Effect-Plug-Ins-Processing/dp/0240825152](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240825152)

Comment: Each dsp algorithm is currently implemented as a single task, and the scheduler schedules it. Is it good to have a loop to complete all instances when the task is scheduled ?  Or any other better ways of scheduling multi instance of dsp tasks.

Comment: It depends on what hardware you are running on and what your goals are.  If you share that info we can give you some tips but ultimately you may just have to profile and see what's fastest on your hardware, if speed is what you are going for!

Comment: The algorithms are for digital communication and runs on communication dsp processors.  Real-time performance has to be guaranteed and a must requirement.

Comment: any help on this. Is dynamic allocation better or static for temporary memory

Comment: Dynamic memory is slower, but static / on the stack memory can be more difficult to use if you don't know how much you'll need. There are tricks to get around that though, like dynamically allocating as much memory as you need, and reusing the same allocated memory each time, only reallocating if you need more memory than you have allocated.

Comment: Basically, memory allocation is slow, so you want to minimize it, but on modern CPUs accessing dynamically allocated memory is no slower than static / global / stack memory. What kind of processor are you using?  Have you made any progress since asking this question?

Comment: Also, don't spend too much time on premature optimization.  Get your code working, then if its too slow, profile to see what the slowness is then optimize that (feel free to ask specific questions about how to make specific things faster).  Optimized code is often easier to make bugs in and harder to maintain, and code often ends up being slow in different places than we expect when writing it.